# Efficient way to recognize time series's granularity in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have multiple time-series as dataframes in Python3, imported from excel files looking like this:

[image: screenshot1]

But they come in varying levels of data granularity such as hourly, daily, monthly and yearly series. To be perfectly clear: within a single file the granularity is consistent, it only varies across the different files. However, there might be missing time stamps (predictable ones like daylight saving or unpredictable ones because of technical failure to record (e.g. in the context of weather data)).

I would like to efficiently recognize each series' granularity level with a function, assuming the first column is always datetime such that an hourly series would have datetime steps like `2022-11-11 01:00` and `2022-11-11 02:00` whereas a yearly series would have datetime steps like `2022-01-01 00:00` and `2023-01-01 00:00`

As a first approach I thought about taking the difference between the datetime series against its lagged series and calculate the average over total horizon to infer on the granularity level, but that seems rather inefficient. I'm hoping there is some built-in function in the datetime package already or that someone can come up with a reliable and more efficient method.

### Edit 1

The above screenshot shows an example of a df featuring daily time-series granularity. Here is another screenshot showing a time-series with hourly granularity:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: I didnt quite get it, you want to redefine your values granularity according to the date column?

Comment: I need to recognize the time-series's granularity. For example, let's say I have 4 dataframes, 2 come with hourly time stamps, 1 with daily time stamps (as shown in screenshot) and 1 with monthly time stamps. Then I want a function that returns an indication of that granularity level. For example relative to 1 year such that the indicator of an hourly series is `8760`, the indicator of a daily series is `365`, ... Or in interger format such that the indicator of an hourly series is `1`, of a daily series `2`, of a monthly series is `3` and yearly series is `4`, ...

Comment: if you have a column `Date` in your dataframe, you can do `df.Date.diff().mode()[0] / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)` to get the most frequent difference between two entries in hours (for your first example this will yield `24.0`, for the second one `1.0`)

Comment: But what if I accidentially select two entries where there are missing data in between? Is there a way to look at the whole datetime seties more holistically?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question: `diff` takes the difference of **all** entries and `mode` selects the most frequent one of these differences. `mode` _always_ returns a Series, even if it's a single number, that's why we take the first element `[0]` of this Series.

Comment: Ohh, that actually sounds perfect! Misunderstanding on my part.